# XNA - Wrap heightmap around sphere

Tags: xna, random, heightmap, planet

I have an idea for a small game which would generate random 3D planets.

I already have found a way to create a random heightmap in XNA (http://adminspot.net/topic/487-cxnamath-fast-procedural-heightmap-generator-snippet/).

How would I be able to wrap the heightmap around a sphere and then render it on the sphere, creating a planet-like terrain? 
Also, would I be able to do something similiar with the .NET port of libnoise (XNA port: http://libnoisedotnet.codeplex.com/)?

I'm not asking for code or anything, just some ideas on how to do something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21232/generating-spherical-world-from-heightmapped-terrain http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45167/square-game-map-rendered-as-sphere